# Continuity of a topological conjugacy $h$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, dynamical-systems

The system $x'=Ax$ is an attractor. Let $h$ be defined by

$$h(0)=0 \qquad h(x)=e^{t_x}e^{t_xA}x$$
where $t_x$ is the real number such that $q(e^{t_x A}x)=1$ and $q(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\langle e^{tA}x,e^{tA}x\rangle\,dt$.

The book says that $h(\cdot)$ is continuous and is the topological conjugacy of $x'=Ax$ and $x'=-x$.

Knowing that $t_x$ is $C^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ I managed to show that $h|_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}}$ is continuous. But I'm not able to show that this function is continuous at 0.

Comment: Can you please first correct whatever is wrong with your formula for $h$? It cannot be $h(x)=e^{t_x}e^{t_x}x$.

Comment: @JohnB I corrected the equation.

Comment: Great. Note that $\sqrt{q(x)}$ is a norm and so it suffices to show that $q(h(x))\to0$ when $x\to0$ (this is the simplest approach).

Comment: @JohnB Can you give me one more hint?

Comment: Sure, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should show that there exist $a,b>0$ such that
$$
a\|x\|^2\le q(x)\le b\|x\|^2.
$$
This follows easily from having an attractor (use the eigenvalues of $A$).

Now observe that
$$
\begin{split}
q(h(x))
&=\int_0^{\infty}\langle e^{tA}e^{t_x}e^{t_xA}x,e^{tA}e^{t_x}e^{t_xA}x\rangle\,dt\\ &=e^{2t_x}\int_0^{\infty}\langle e^{tA}e^{t_xA}x,e^{tA}e^{t_xA}x\rangle\,dt\\
&=e^{2t_x}q(e^{t_xA}x)=e^{2t_x}.
\end{split}
$$
Therefore,
$$
a\|h(x)\|^2\le e^{2t_x}\le b\|h(x)\|^2.
$$
On the other hand, since
$$
1=q(e^{t_xA}x) =\int_0^{\infty}\| e^{(t+t_x)A}x\|^2\,dt= \int_{t_x}^{\infty}\| e^{tA}x\|^2\,dt,
$$
we find that if $x\to0$, then $t_x\to-\infty$. It follows from $$a\|h(x)\|^2\le e^{2t_x}$$ that $h(x)\to0$ when $x\to0$. The other inequality can be used for the inverse.

Comment: My problem was at the step that you put out of the inner product $e^{t_x}$, as he depended on $x$ I thought I couldn't

Comment: It is a constant, so you can take it out.